# Admin SDK Audit Service returns 400 Bad request

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-admin-sdk

I'm using the Google Admin SDK and am trying to set up a MailMonitor for an audit. Here is the code I am currently using

```
            MailMonitor monitor = new MailMonitor();
            monitor.BeginDate = new DateTime(2013, 11, 8);
            monitor.EndDate = new DateTime(2013, 12, 30);
            monitor.IncomingEmailMonitorLevel = MonitorLevel.FULL_MESSAGE;
            monitor.OutgoingEmailMonitorLevel = MonitorLevel.FULL_MESSAGE;
            monitor.DraftMonitorLevel = MonitorLevel.FULL_MESSAGE;
            monitor.ChatMonitorLevel = MonitorLevel.FULL_MESSAGE;
            monitor.DestinationUserName = "adminUser";

            AuditService service = new AuditService("domain.com", "domain.com-auditapp-v1");
            service.setUserCredentials("adminUser@domain.com", "password");

            MailMonitor monitorEntry = service.CreateMailMonitor("userToMonitor", monitor);
```

When I run this code I get a 400 Bad Request returned. The credentials I'm using for the adminUser are correct. I've triple checked that. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was because the **BeginDate** variable needs to be at a time that's is exactly at the present (to the second), or at some point the future. This time also needs to be converted to UTC time in order for it to work.